# Updates & transactions in Spring Data JPA

Tags: java, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, spring-transactions

I am making an updating native query within my Spring Data JPA Repository.

```
@Query(nativeQuery=true, value="update t_table set change = 0 where id = ?1")
@Modifying(clearAutomatically=false)
void disableChange(int id);
```

The value is updated in a correct way as I can see with my database client but next transactions are not recognizing the change until the server is redeployed.

My service looks like this:

```
@Service("my.service.class.service")
public final class MyServiceClassImpl implements MyServiceClass 
{

    @Autowired
    private ClientRepository clientRepository;


    @Override
    @Secured("MY_ROLE")
    @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW, rollbackFor=MyException.class)
    public void myMethod() throws PlayTheGuruException 
    {
         //
         myMethod();
         //
    }

    private void myMethod() throws MyException {
         //
         clientRepository.disableChange(22);
         //
    }
}
```

May I need to annotate `myMethod` with transactional and mandatory propagation or something like that?

Is the native query the problem?

This issue appears only with updating queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a stale value from L2 cache, if L2 cache is enabled for the entity in question.

Try to remove affected entity from L2 cache manually:

```
@Autowired EntityManagerFactory emf;

...

clientRepository.disableChange(22);
emf.getCache().evict(..., 22);
```